# Ionicv1 build android fails with input files use or override a deprecated API

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic v1 for building and android app, however fails to build android with the following error. I have given the output of ionic info below for my env.

> BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 18.769 secs
Error: /Users/..../platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper;`

ionic info:
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
    Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3
    Node  : v8.9.1
    npm   : 5.5.1
    OS    : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55